# Display only single varation of product from WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I try to learn WooCommerce and I want to display as "featured" only one variation of a product. Is it possible? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: One variation? Do you mean from a category or from the same kind of product?

Comment: Let's think about a product - it can have a couploe of variations (for example, colours). I want to display that products variation (eg. `blue`).

Comment: Ok.. And how are you using the variations with woocommerce? To identify them.

Comment: For now, I can only display them at the product page. More info here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations/

Comment: Currently it's not possible straight out of the box with woocommerce, but this doesn't mean it can't be done! You can write your plugin to do this with woocommerce, I dont know how good your php is, but you will need to write your own functions and incorporate it with woocommerce, read more about wordpress plugin api here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API